# How to insert data into objects iterated by Yii CActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii, cactivedataprovider

I have a strange request and I'm not sure there is a better way other than simply brute force, but I have a CActiveDataProvider being rendered and virtual properties of the underlying Model are being used.

I would like to be able to pass extra information to that Model to filter the calculations in those virtual properties.

For example, assume there is a virtual property method getCreated_Widget_Count() that returns the number of widgets that the entity (let's say it is a widget maker) has created it its lifetime.

I would like to be able to filter the count to a specific date range.

So I want to be Create a CActiveDataProvider and use it in a CListView to display each of the elements, and the view is accessing property created_widget_count.  But I want it to, sometimes, limit the result to a number based on an date range.

The obvious thing to do is iterate over the entire data set first and set the range to filter in each object, but I was hoping that there was a way to pass information to the CActiveDataProvider that could get into each constructor so that could be done while they are being built.

Any ideas?

Comment: The way I'd do it it to have the date ranges for the filter as virtual properties that are set while the ActiveRecord is being initialized. That way, when I call `$model->createdWidgetCount`, the `getCreated_Widget_Count` method uses the values to set the widgetCount.